# User Model Setup for Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I would like to know what is the best setup to make User model for Pundit. (MySQL)
I want:

- role: admin, default_user, ..
- groups

I find this tutorial: https://medium.com/@toddbaur/using-devise-and-pundit-with-rails-5-to-delegate-authorization-to-users-22f2c83d0244 but it use postgresql and uuid whereas mysql doesn't have uuid..

Thanks!

Comment: Just follow the tutorial and replace the uuid to integer ID,

Comment: Integer ID needs to be auto-increment ?

Comment: That is handled by default from rails framework no worries, even you dont need to specify the ID in the columns it will be automatically added to the table.

Comment: more information on the documentation, please read it and understand everything in this section before migrating the user table
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-table

Comment: This is kind of a nonsense question and is way to broad to be answerable. Pundit is just a toolkit to build authentication systems based on object oriented design patterns. Besides being able to find users it actually gives about 0 fawks about your user model. Its like asking what the best kind of car for driving on road is. If you want to have a role based access system (which it kind of sounds like you are describing) you actually have to build it or use something like Rolify.